# Android getResource in non activity class from an Non Activity Class?

Tags: android, resources, android-manifest

I got this following method in an non Activity class, My code is below.

```
public class ReadTextByLineNo  {

public void setContext(Context _context) {
    if (context == null) {
        context = _context;
    }
}
public String getTextByLine(int Filename,int LineNumber)
{


    String output="";
    String line="";
    int counter=1;
    try
    {
         InputStream in = context.getResources().openRawResource(Filename);
        //InputStream in = assetManager.open(Filename);
        if(in!=null)
        {
            InputStreamReader input = new InputStreamReader(in);
            BufferedReader buff = new BufferedReader(input);
            while((line=buff.readLine())!=null)
            {
                if(counter ==LineNumber){
                    output=line;
                }counter++;
            }in.close();
        }else{
            Log.e("Input STREAM PROBLEM", "TEXT IS NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL");
        }
    }catch(Exception e)
    {
        //log
    }

    return output;
}
```

> **I am calling this method from an NON_ACTIVITY CLASS LIKE THIS **

```
class sample implements Isample
{
ReadTextByLineNo read = new ReadTextByLineNo();
String subMsg =  read.getTextByLine(R.raw.subtitle, storySceneId);
//the above string is to called from an activity called Layout 


}
```

How do I use resources/context from an non activity class?  I cannot use the context in constructor since I'm also calling the method from an non Activity class.
so I can't set read.setContent(this); where I got setContext method in my ReadtextByLineNo class, thanks for the help .

Please help me to get the context/resourse in the class sample and example by code is appreciated

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
public class ReadTextByLineNo  {
    private static Context context;

    public static void setContext(Context mcontext) {
        if (context == null)
            context = mcontext;
    }
}
```

when your application start, just initialize this context, by calling

```
ReadTextByLineNo.setContext(getApplicationContext());
```

from your main activity..

Enjoy...

Comment: IM not calling the method from an activity so how to use this in non Activity class ReadTextByLineNo.setContext(getApplicationContext());

Comment: dude,dont call this method from non Activity, call this method from any other activity just to set context, now don't tell me you don not have any Activity in your app. :D, call it from your first activity, just to set the context,, it is simple...